# Authorize request to API by React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, cookies, axios, httpcookie

I want to use Santum with Laravel and I have a problem with Authorize. Sanctum works becouse I can take response if I send request via Postman. But I don;t understand how authorization works in React. Look at my code.
Here I generated token and save that in a cookie (I have httponly)

```
public function getToken(){
    $user = User::first();
    $token = $user->createToken('Authrization', ['server:update'])->plainTextToken;
    Cookie::queue("Authorization", $token);

    return $token;
}
```

In React I wanted use this token automatically (I read that this is possibe by withCreditional). Co I read this code

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/token')
     .then(response => {
         console.log(response.data.token);
     });
const json = axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/taks/all-tasks', { method: 'GET', withCredentials: true }).then(res => {
    j = this.res.data;
    return j;
})
console.log('Json' + json)
```

But I have an error (401). How can I authorize access to *all-tasks* route and route with the simples way?

Comment: `withCredentials` kind of implies the server is cross-origin. If that's the case the cookie also needs to be `Secure` and have a `SameSite=None` policy and your server needs to be served over https.

Comment: I'm testing that on localhost and I can't using https protocol

Comment: Probably better to put the authorisation token in local storage and send it in the Authorisation header.

Comment: But it doesn't safe method. I am exposed to XSS attack.